# Comparing the two objects in an array with variables to display the third object

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, javascript-objects

I have an array "languageCodes". I gotta compare the objects "ssmlGender" and "languageCodes" with the variables "genderSelected" and "languageSelected" respectively. If both are true, I have to display the corresponding "name" fields of the array. I did try two level filtering with forEach and stored the value in the Array. But, only got the empty one.

```
let languageCodes = [
{ languageCodes: ['es-ES'], name: 'es-ES-Standard-A', ssmlGender: 'FEMALE', naturalSampleRateHertz: 2403},
{languageCodes: ['it-IT'], name: 'it-IT-Standard-A', ssmlGender: 'MALE', naturalSampleRateHertz: 21000},
{languageCodes: ['ja-JP'], name: 'ja-JP-Standard-A', ssmlGender: 'FEMALE', naturalSampleRateHertz: 3200},
{languageCodes: ['ko-KR'], name: 'ko-KR-Standard-A', ssmlGender: 'MALE', naturalSampleRateHertz: 2330},
{languageCodes: ['en-US'], name: 'en-US-Wavenet-B', ssmlGender: 'FEMALE', naturalSampleRateHertz: 412},
{languageCodes: ['en-GB'], name: 'en-GB-Standard-A', ssmlGender: 'MALE', naturalSampleRateHertz: 8493}
];
```

My JavaScript Function:

```
function changeVoiceNameOption() {
            const languageSelected = document.getElementById('languages').value;
            let entriesElement = document.getElementById('entries');
            entriesElement.innerHTML = '';
            entriesElement.innerHTML += '<option value="" selected>Choose your option</option>'
            var nameArray=[];
            languageCodes.filter(( item ) => {
                return item.ssmlGender.includes(genderSelected);
            }).forEach(( filteredItems ) =>  {
                filteredItems.languageCodes.forEach(( languageCode ) => {      
                    return filteredItems.languageCodes.includes(languageSelected);                        
                })
            }).forEach(( filteredItems ) =>  {
                entriesElement.innerHTML += `<option value="${item.name}"> ${item.name} </option>`
            })
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering can be done in a simplified manner. Assuming `genderSelected` variable is declared, this should work:

```
function changeVoiceNameOption() {

    const languageSelected = document.getElementById('languages').value;
    let entriesElement = document.getElementById('entries');

    const filteredItems = languageCodes.filter(({languageCodes: langs, ssmlGender: gender}) => langs[0] === languageSelected && gender === genderSelected);

    entriesElement.innerHTML = '';
    entriesElement.innerHTML += '<option value="" selected>Choose your option</option>'

    filteredItems.forEach(item => entriesElement.innerHTML += `<option value="${item.name}"> ${item.name} </option>`);

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked. Could you please explain the operation over here in this line `const filteredItems = languageCodes.filter(({languageCodes: langs, ssmlGender: gender}) => langs[0] === languageSelected && gender === genderSelected)` -why do we declare langs[0] and not with gender as gender[0]?

Comment: @srikha: ‘langs’ is an alias for languageCodes, and it is an array as given in your example, hence we are accessing it with [0]. ‘gender’ is an alias for ssmlGender, which is a string, and we access it direclty. The aliasing is done as a part of ES6 object assignment destructuring. The filter function simply checks for two conditions: if first item in langs array is equal to the one selected, and if the  gender is equal to the specified one

Comment: Cool. Now, I am getting it. Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This lines look incorrect:

```
languageCodes.filter(( item ) => {
    return item.languageCodes.includes(genderSelected);
})
```

You are filtering the languages against the genderSelected, that will return an empty array

Plus in the forEach you return and then try to push, the nameArray.push will never happen

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. Was confused with same array name and object name. Now I have changed the array. Still couldn't get the output.